# Unable to store array in local Storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, local

So basically i am trying to create from which stores some user info in local storage and updates and delete the information of the user i just started working on it but got stuck at inserting complete users data in local storage.
whenever i am storing users data i am getting (object : Object) in my local Storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name Here">
Id: <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Enter id Here"><br><br>


<button onclick="myFunction()" >Submit</button>
<br>
<br>


<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
 function myFunction(){   

  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;  
     var id = document.getElementById("id").value;  

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    var person = [ firstName: fname , ID : id  ];

    var tempitem =[ [localStorage.getItem("record")] ];

    console.log();

    tempitem.push(person);

     localStorage.setItem("record",  tempitem);
     //Check if an item can be deleted using index number


}
else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}

}






</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `var person = [ firstName: fname , ID : id  ];` that does not do what you think - is your **actual code** more like `var person = { firstName: fname , ID : id  };`

Comment: localStorage stores **strings** - an Object to String produces "[object Object]" ... use JSON.stringify when storing and JSON.parse when reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the storage of data in local storage is it very important to remember you can only store string values. When storing objects or array (or arrays of objects) you must convert the data to JSON first.

This is simple:

```
localStorage.setItem("record", JSON.stringify(data));
```

And to read the value again:

```
var record = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("record"));
```

If you do not do this Javascript will try to stringify the data itself using the `toString()` method. For objects this means the value `[object Object]` will be stored and not the actual contents of the object.

Also it appears you are confusing Javascript objects and arrays.

This is an object:

```
{
    firstName: "John"
    ID: "10"
}
```

And this is an array:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Note the use of '{' and '}' when defining an object and the use of '[' and ']' when defining an array. Also note we can have named property in an object which we cannot have in an array.

An array of objects would then look like this:

```
[
    {
        firstName: "John"
        ID: "10"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Mary"
        ID: "20"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i filter data stored in local Storage using ID?

Answer (score 0):

As localStorage only deals with strings, you'll need to use JSON.parse/JSON.stringify as follows

```
function myFunction(){     
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;  
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;  

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // note: using {} ... person is an Object, not an Array
        var person = {firstName: fname , ID : id  };

        // use JSON.parse to parse the string to an Object 
        var tempitem =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("record") || "[]");
        // || [] so of it doesn't exist, returns an empty array to push to
        tempitem.push(person);

        // stringify the Object to store as a string
        localStorage.setItem("record",  JSON.stringify(tempitem));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i filter data stored in local Storage using ID?

Comment: Get it from storage. Filter the usual way. Write to storage

Answer (score 0):

localStorage stores item in strings, so in your case, you should do like this:

`localStorage.setItem("record",  JSON.stringify(tempitem))`

and if you want to get it from localStorage you do:

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('record'))`